# Variables in Powershell including new line characters

Tags: xaml, powershell

I am fairly new to PowerShell, but I have created a XAML form to do some health checking on our environment. In the first portion I have created an if statement to check the connection state of a device. The device name is pulled from a `TextBox` and then, if that device is connected, it continues the health check. However when the item is pulling from the `TextBox` it is including the "`n" for the line so the query fails. Here is the relevant code...

```
    Remove-Item C:\Healthlog.txt
#This is where the problem is happening
$Computers = $CompNames.Text.Split("`n")

Foreach ($Comp in $Computers){

    $log= "C:\Healthlog.txt"
    Add-Content $log "$Comp"

    #Check to see if machines are connected
    Write-Host "$TestConnection = Test-Connection -ComputerName $Comp -    Quiet"
    $TestConnection = Test-Connection -ComputerName $Comp -Quiet
    Write-Host $TestConnection
    If ($TestConnection -eq $False) {
    Add-Content $log "Connection to Device has failed"
    }
```

`$Compnames` is the name of the variable the `TextBox` has been assigned to.

The output is a failed query every time because the new line character is being included in the variable. I have tried doing a `-replace` on `$Comp` as well as `$Computers`, but I am not sure if I am doing that right.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the output of this command:

```
("1`n2`n").Split("`r`n").Count
```

The output is `3` because the third line is empty. You can work around this by ignoring empty entries (which I think is what you want):

```
$CompNames.Text.Split("`r`n", [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's a just a newline value that is messing up? Have you tried replacing carrage return as well?

```
$Computers = $CompNames.Text.Split("`n")
Foreach ($Comp in $Computers)
{

    $newComp = $Comp.Replace("`n", "").Replace("`r", "")

    $log= "C:\Healthlog.txt"
    Add-Content $log "$newComp"

    #Check to see if machines are connected
    Write-Host "$TestConnection = Test-Connection -ComputerName $newComp -    Quiet"
    $TestConnection = Test-Connection -ComputerName $newComp -Quiet
    Write-Host $TestConnection
    If ($TestConnection -eq $False) {
    Add-Content $log "Connection to Device has failed"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So based on both the comments in here I got the code functional. It was an issue with both the empty entries and the carriage return. The final code ended up looking like this.

```
$Computers = $CompNames.text.split("`n", [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) | % { $_.replace("`r", "") }
```

Comment: Shorter is simply `$CompNames.text.split("\`r\`n", [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)`. Updated my answer to include the `\`r`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!